# Executar Evento Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

estou com o seguinte problema ao tentar clicar em uma paginação usando python e selenium

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A paginação é uma tabela

```
<td class="dr-dscr-inact rich-datascr-inact" onclick="Event.fire(this, 'rich:datascroller:onscroll', {'page': '2});">2</td>
```

criei o seguinte método

```
def Proxima_pagina():
#pego o id da tabela onde está a paginação
    tabela = Driver.find_element_by_id('form:j_id162:dtRick_table')

#faço um for em todos os td e mando clicar
    for td in tabela.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='dr-dscr-inact rich-datascr-inact']"):

        td.click()
```

ele inciar no primeiro clicar no 2, porém da o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Então amigo, funciona assim, esse erro diz respeito a referencia de elemento, você tem a referencia do elemento **porem ele não encontra-se na tela**.

Você vai achar estranho pois esta vendo o elemento na tela, porém a referencia é ao objeto antigo, assim que você clicou na próxima pagina, a tabela na tela já não é a mesma, assim sua referencia esta 'desatualizada'.

Como resolver:

Pegue a pagina atual, e em seguida procure pela próxima, caso tenha, clique.
Se você, pegar o total no momento, pode ser que depois do 9 tenha mais paginas e você acabaria não considerando elas.

Exemplo:

```py
def proxima_pagina():
   # Pega a página atual, a pagina selecionada no momento deve ter algum atributo único.
   current_page = Driver.find_element_by_xpath('XPATH_DA_PAGINA_DO_MOMENTO')

   # Procura pela próxima e clica, caso não encontre vai parar e mostrar a mensagem.
   try:
       next_page = current_page.find_element_by_xpath('/following-sibling::td[1]')
       next_page.click()
   except NoSuchElementException:
       print('No more pages')
```

Vai precisar desse import aqui:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

E caso você queira sair clicando em todas as paginas, você faz um **for** chamando o método.

Comment: Obrigado pela reposta. A página me parece se carregada por Ajax.

Comment: Ainda deu erro? Qual foi o resultado?

Answer (score -1):

Conseguir resolver com o seguinte código.

```
def Total_pagina():
    time.sleep(3)
    tabela = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='dr-dscr-inact rich-datascr-inact']")
    total = len(tabela)
    return total + 1

def Proxima_pagina():
    for A in range(1, Total_pagina()):
        thisEl = Driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//td[contains(@class, "rich-datascr-inact") and contains(text(), "{0}")]'.format(str(A + 1)))
        time.sleep(6)
        baixar()
        thisEl.click()
        time.sleep(6)
```